# Jolt Removing Object when value is Equal to Something

Tags: json, jolt

I have an input like this -

```
[
  {
    "time": "2014-10-31T01:59:59.000+10:00",
    "value": {
      "nil": null
    },
    "metadata": {
      "TVPMeasurementMetadata": {
        "qualifier": {
          "title": null,
          "href": null
        }
      }
    },
    "longitude": "115.1248985",
    "latitude": "-33.963617",
    "gathered_time": "1685662804091"
  },
  {
    "time": "2014-11-30T02:00:00.000+10:00",
    "value": {
      "nil": null
    },
    "metadata": {
      "TVPMeasurementMetadata": {
        "qualifier": {
          "title": null,
          "href": null
        }
      }
    },
    "longitude": "115.1248985",
    "latitude": "-33.963617",
    "gathered_time": "1685662804091"
  },
  {
    "time": "2014-12-10T02:00:00.000+10:00",
    "value": 83.939,
    "metadata": null,
    "longitude": "115.1248985",
    "latitude": "-33.963617",
    "gathered_time": "1685662804091"
  },
  {
    "time": "2014-12-11T02:00:00.000+10:00",
    "value": 84.089,
    "metadata": null,
    "longitude": "115.1248985",
    "latitude": "-33.963617",
    "gathered_time": "1685662804091"
  }
]
```

What I want is to only get values the JSON objects that have numerical data in them and don't equal  {"nil": null} ... Here's what the expected output looks like.

```
[
    {
      "time" : "2014-12-10T02:00:00.000+10:00",
      "value" : 83.939,
      "metadata" : null,
      "longitude" : "115.1248985",
      "latitude" : "-33.963617",
      "gathered_time" : "1685662804091"
    }, {
      "time" : "2014-12-11T02:00:00.000+10:00",
      "value" : 84.089,
      "metadata" : null,
      "longitude" : "115.1248985",
      "latitude" : "-33.963617",
      "gathered_time" : "1685662804091"
    }
]
```

I tried a couple different specs operations like remove but those didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": {
          "nil": {
            "null": {
              "": ""
            }
          },
          "*": {
            "@2": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is your Jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value_temp": "@(1,value)",
        "value_tem*": ["=toInteger", "null"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value_temp": {
          "*": {
            "@2": "data.&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "null": "",
        "*": {
          "value_temp": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```